# Can Vue Pages get updated variables value without any rebuild or redeployment?

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, aws-fargate

I am working on pilot project and deploying on AWS Fargate. One of the requirement is I need to configure some variables value which I can change on the fly through aws browser console and application should use updated value of those variables without any rebuild or redeployment.
application witten in vuejs. I am looking what are the possible ways

much appreciate for your suggestion.

Comment: you may have to reference an external database and fetch that content when your app loads (like a content management system). In my experience there's no way to dynamically inject settings or content into a built app. You will have to fetch it.

Comment: @slowFooMovement : I don't have database. We have api calls only. what about If I maintain file on s3 and everytime read it from there ?

Comment: that sounds like a good solution! Please let me know if that works for you @IMparasharG